# Running a snakemake pipeline for multiple datasets

Tags: snakemake

I have a snakemake pipeline with rules that call other programs and custom R and python scripts.

I have multiple datasets on which this same pipeline needs to run. Usually I would make a separate folder for each dataset and put a config file specific to the dataset and run it individually.

As I have 20+ datasets this time, I was wondering if there is a more automated way to do this. There are mainly 4 parameters which change between the datasets: input file location, primer, quality control parameter and output dir for results.
Is there a way to have a 'master' config file which would have information on these 4 parameters and a snakefile which then calls the second snakefile as many times as the number for datasets?

**This whole idea seems like a for loop to me which loops through arrays of these 4 parameters but I can't figure out how to implement it in snakemake.**

Any suggestions and ideas are welcome!
Thanks
Hena

Comment: Does `subworkflow` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Provided all the parameters are somewhat "encoded" in the output file names, I think this can be done using a single snakefile.

Your main configuration file would include a section for each dataset, and this section could contain the desired output directory as well as a path to a configuration file specific to this dataset.

Proof of concept:

`Snakefile`:

```python
import yaml

datasets = list(config.keys())

results = []
for dataset in datasets:
    out_dir = config[dataset]["out_dir"]
    with open(config[dataset]["conf"]) as conf_fh:
        dat_conf = yaml.safe_load(conf_fh)
        p1 = dat_conf["p1"]
        p2 = dat_conf["p2"]
        p3 = dat_conf["p3"]
        p4 = dat_conf["p4"]
    results.append(f"{out_dir}/{p1}_{p2}_{p3}_{p4}.out")


rule all:
    input:
        results


rule make_output:
    output:
        "{out_dir}/{p1}_{p2}_{p3}_{p4}.out"
    shell:
        "touch {output[0]}"
```

`main_config.yaml`:

```
dat1:
    out_dir: "dat1"
    conf: "dat1_conf.yaml"
dat2:
    out_dir: "dat2"
    conf: "dat2_conf.yaml"
```

`dat1_conf.yaml`:

```
p1: "A"
p2: "a"
p3: "1"
p4: "01"
```

`dat2_conf.yaml`:

```
p1: "B"
p2: "b"
p3: "2"
p4: "02"
```

Can be executed, for instance, as follows:

```
snakemake --snakefile Snakefile --configfile main_config.yaml -j 2
```

This creates the following result files:

```
dat1/A_a_1_01.out
dat2/B_b_2_02.out
```

Comment: Agreed, a single pipeline scanning over all datasets would usually be the idiomatic way. I always try to end up with one pipeline per project/paper. Also note that you can put all of these dataset parameters into a TSV file and use pandas+[paramspace](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=paramspace#parameter-space-exploration) to explore them.

Comment: I didn't know about `Paramspace`. Interesting feature, thanks. I imagine endless discussions between developers regarding the choice of the default value for `param_sep`.

Comment: Thanks bli for answering my question in such detail! @JohannesKöster I am trying to use paramspace but I am not sure how to pass on the values from paramspace.instance to something like a cutadapt shell command. How do I access them individually in a shell command rather than passing them to a python script.
Thanks!

Comment: You put paramspace.instance into the params of the rule, and then you format the shell command with things like `{instance[myparam]}`. Note the missing quotes around the key name. This is normal Python formatting syntax.

Comment: Thanks both! It took me a while to get started on this code but I am working on it now. The first one being how do I pass on the samples for the different datasets. Right now samples are read at the beginning of the Snakefile  as SampleTable = pd.read_table(config['sampletable'],index_col=0)
SAMPLES = list(SampleTable.index) and then this is used throughout in different rules. How do I make it work with paramspace now where that is just a file with the location of this sample.tsv file